Error "expected top-level entity" when using emsdk:3.1.64, but not when using emsdk:3.1.26
My code compiled when using emsdk:3.1.64, but not when using emsdk:3.1.26
emcc C:\test\hello_world.cpp -O3    -r -o C:\test\libar.bc && emcc  C:\test\libar.bc  -O3   -o 
C:\testtest_wasm.js C:\test\libar.bc:1:2: error: expected top-level entity     1 | 
<U+0000>asm<U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000><U+0001>0<U+0008>`<U+0002><U+007F><U+007F><U+0001>
<U+007F>`<U+0003>...       |         ^ 1 error generated. emcc: error: 
'C:/Users/user/Documents/habr/emsdk-main/upstream/bin\clang.exe -target wasm32-unknown-
emscripten -fignore-exceptions -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-
emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr --sysroot=C:\Users\user\Documents\habr\emsdk-
main\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot -DEMSCRIPTEN -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -
Xclang -iwithsysroot/include\fakesdl -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include\compat -O3 C:\test\libar.bc -
c -o C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_tvmixm4o\libar_0.o' failed (returned 1) 

or if I remove -r and -O3:
emcc C:\test\hello_world.cpp  -o C:\test\libar.bc && emcc  C:\test\libar.bc   -o 
C:\testtest_wasm.js emcc: warning: object file output extension (.bc) used for non-object 
output.  If you meant to build an object file please use `-c, `-r`, or `-shared` [-Wemcc] 
C:\test\libar.bc:1:1: error: expected top-level entity     1 | // include: shell.js       | ^ 1 
error generated. emcc: error: 'C:/Users/user/Documents/habr/emsdk-main/upstream/bin\clang.exe -
target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -fignore-exceptions -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-
analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr --
sysroot=C:\Users\user\Documents\habr\emsdk-main\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot -DEMSCRIPTEN -
Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include\fakesdl -Xclang -
iwithsysroot/include\compat C:\test\libar.bc -c -o 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_m43yxogd\libar_0.o' failed (returned 1)

C:\test\hello_world.cpp:
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello world";

    return 0;
}

If I use emsdk:3.1.26, there is no error. Why?

I have a similar issue did you found a solution?
